# Python Client/Server hangs

Tags: python, sockets

I have an Android app, written in Javascript (source not available) that allows the creation of Buttons and sending Button presses.

The Server is running on a Win10 desktop, and the code is as follows:

```
# Try.py

import socket

CRLF = '\r\n'
count = 0
port = 6666  

print('Server Waiting on ' + str(port))
host = socket.gethostname()
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together
sock.listen(5)
conn, address = sock.accept()  # accept new connection
print("Connection from: " + str(address))

data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
# the Client sends a message containing the Client's Version NO
# and the screen size
print(data)

while True:
    count = count + 1
    
    conn.send(('AAA=Button~Text=' + str(count) + CRLF).encode())
    # this command sends a message to the client to create a Button
    # named AAA (if it does not exists) and changes the the label = count
    
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    # reply from the Client ("40=40" if message was OK)
    
    if data == '':
        break
    print(data)
    
    conn.send(('40' + CRLF).encode())
    print(count)
    # this command passes control to the client
    # until the Button is pressed
    
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    # Client replies after the button press with "40=40~AAA=1"
    # "40=40" means the message received was  correct
    # AAA is the button ID, and 1 means a short press
    print(data)
    
conn.close()  # close the connection
```

The code works for a while (for a few minutes) after which it just hangs.

Here is the dump of the packets (using SmartSniff):

```
[1/17/2023 8:00:27 PM:508]
EasyGUI_V1.0 ScreenSize: (1440x2412)
[1/17/2023 8:00:27 PM:508]
AAA=Button~Text=1

[1/17/2023 8:00:27 PM:514]
40=40
[1/17/2023 8:00:27 PM:514]
40

[1/17/2023 8:00:30 PM:049]
40=40~AAA=1
[1/17/2023 8:00:30 PM:049]
AAA=Button~Text=2

[1/17/2023 8:00:30 PM:068]
40=40
[1/17/2023 8:00:30 PM:070]
40

[1/17/2023 8:00:33 PM:590]
40=40~AAA=1
[1/17/2023 8:00:33 PM:591]
AAA=Button~Text=3

[1/17/2023 8:00:33 PM:597]
40=40
[1/17/2023 8:00:33 PM:597]
40
```

Is there something wrong with my Server code ???
Is it a timing problem ???

Comment: It is unclear where it hangs, i.e. if the client is waiting for the server or the server for the client. It is unclear if the server implements the client protocol properly and complete, since nothing is known about the client protocol. While one can write a client which works properly with this server, it is not clear how your specific client really behaves.

Comment: I found the problem. Android after a certain time puts the app in the background, so the Client cannot reply to the Server.

Comment: The only way around this (that I can think of) is to have an Async timer in the Server that after a specified time (while the Client is still in the foreground) terminates the Client, and then closes and opens the socket awaiting the manual reload of the Client. This timer should restart after each time the client sends a message.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to write the async timer! Any help would be welcome.